# Is it better to include an object in every class or only when it's needed?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the class 'Pizza':

Option 1:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, tools):
        self.tools = tools
        self.slices = []

    def cut(self, slices: int):
        self.slices = self.tools.pizza_cutter(slices=slices)

    def eat(self, slices: int):
        if len(self.slices) => slices:
            diff = len(self.slices) - slices
            self.slices[:diff]
        else:
            print('Not enough slices to eat!')
```

Option 2:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self):
        self.slices = []

    def cut(self, slices: int, tools):
        self.slices = tools.pizza_cutter(slices=slices)

    def eat(self, slices: int):
        if len(self.slices) => slices:
            diff = len(self.slices) - slices
            self.slices[:diff]
        else:
            print('Not enough slices to eat!')
```

As you can see it either loads `tools` in `__init__`, or it just receives the `tools` instance in the method that actually uses it.

I am wondering, what is the best approach? Consider that there are multiple instances of `Pizza` created each loop and that at the end of this loop I `cut()` all the `Pizza`s

Comment: Is tool associated with the pizza or with the cut?

Comment: Both, after all, it is a pizza cutter.

Comment: If every instance of `Pizza` will need to use a `tools`, then it should probably be passed to the constructor, or simply assigned in the constructor, like: `self.tools = Tools()`. (assuming `Tools` is also a class you have somewhere).

Comment: What if you need to cut it with two different tools?

Comment: The second one for me, definitely. Making `tools` a property of pizza is contre-intuitive and bring unecessary complexity.

Comment: The modeling sems a little odd. A method is usually analogous to a *verb*, but `pizza_cutter` is a noun. It seems like that should be an object with a `cut` method that takes a pizza as an argument.

Comment: Does the Tools ever change, are there different tools, does it matter? if not, you can have it internally to pizza, otherwise, as a parameter in the constructor or the method it uses it. ALSO! Will you use the tools in more that one method in the Pizza class? Do you need it as a pizza attribute or not?

Comment: if the pizza class is dependent on tools class then it is better to inherit the dependent function in pizza class and then proceed further.

Comment: @Petronella The tools do not change, no, I won't use the `Tools` in any other method in the pizza class, nope, I don't need it as an attribute. It just makes it 'cleaner' to include it in the `__init__`

Comment: In this case I would take it as a simple parameter for the method cut. Even, you might not even need it, just create the method cut and say in how many parts or when is it cut, not with what. A pizza is cut and that's it. Only if it matters with what you should consider it. You also don't consider on what the pizza is cut, wooden surface, metal, plate etc.

Comment: When does it make sense to pick what to cut a pizza with? When it is made or before you eat it?

Comment: Of course the `pizza` class and the `pizza_cutter` are an analogy to something else I'm working on, the way it's designed follows my real program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I will determine whether or not to include something in a class by how I would describe it.

- The first instance of your class Pizza contains all of the parts of the pizza and the tools to cut it.
- The second class Pizza contains all the parts of a pizza.

When the word "and" comes into play I know that I've put too much into one class and need to separate it out. In this case, the tools are not an inherent part of a pizza. You can have a pizza without the tools to cut it. Pizza might be hard to cut without tools, but that doesn't make it any less of a pizza.

With this in mind, I would recommend keeping tools out of your pizza

Comment: At that point though I would probably change the structure of the class to include whether or not the pizza has been cut, then if someone tries to eat it without the pizza being cut they would be notified appropriately